# getting Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY: installPackageLI] in Android studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

As per this [blogpost](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/10/31/android-studio-3p0-flag-test-only.html) from CommonsWare, `AndroidManifest.xml` file can have an `android:testOnly` attribute.

In my `AndroidManifest.xml` it is set as "false"

```
android:testOnly="false"
```

And I am generating the apk file using the “Build APK(s)” menu option as shown below image,

[image]

And when i am trying to install app from command line, adb install -r myapp.apk, I am still getting error,

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY: installPackageLI]

Android studio version is as below,
[image]

What else shall I do to make my app run?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you really want to be able to remove the test flag from the APK generated in Android Studio, you could try adding the following to your gradle.properties file:

> android.injected.testOnly = false

Comment: i searched a lot and did whatever was there in @Commnsware blog, nothing helped. When I used above flag in gradle.properties it worked perfectly! Thanks

Comment: Does it mean that debug apk's are built with this flag (testOnly = true) by default?

Comment: @RobD Would I be able to release this build on play-store with key set as android.injected.testOnly = false or should I revert it back to "true" when I am uploading to play-store?

Answer (score 170):

You can also use command like this :

```
adb install -r -t myapp.apk
```

it works for me:

```
PS C:\Users\languoguang> adb -P 12345 install -r D:\GreeneTrans\HelloWorld-signed.apk
adb: failed to install D:\GreeneTrans\HelloWorld-signed.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY: installPackageLI]
PS C:\Users\languoguang> adb -P 12345 install -t D:\GreeneTrans\HelloWorld-signed.apk
Success
PS C:\Users\languoguang> adb -P 12345 install -r -t D:\GreeneTrans\HelloWorld-signed.apk
Success
PS C:\Users\languoguang>
```

Comment: What does it mean -r -t?

Answer (score 48):

Just use the following command:

```
adb install -t app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk
```

You do not need to use -r, -r means Reinstall an existing app, keeping its data.

> Install an app You can use adb to install an APK on an emulator or
>   connected device with the install command:
>
> adb install path_to_apk
>
> You must use the -t option with the install command when you install a
>   test APK. For more information, see -t.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#move

> -t: Allow test APKs to be installed. Gradle generates a test APK when you have only run or debugged your app or have used the Android Studio
>   Build > Build APK command. If the APK is built using a developer
>   preview SDK (if the targetSdkVersion is a letter instead of a number),
>   you must include the -t option with the install command if you are
>   installing a test APK.

https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#-t-option

Or you could use the same command as you click Run in Android Studio

```
adb push {project dir}/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/{appId}

adb shell pm install -t /data/local/tmp/{appId}
```

appId is defined in the app/build.gradle.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId appId
```

Now the app is installed from locally on the device
Launch the first activity.

```
adb shell am start -n "{package name}/{package name}.splash.SplashActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

> 2019-11-13 13:43  Gradle sync started
>
> 13:44 Project setup started
>
> 13:44 Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources,
>   :vplus_explore:generateDebugSources,
>   :vplus_uibase:generateDebugSources,
>   :vplus_widget:generateDebugSources,
>   :vplus_runtime:generateDebugSources,
>   :vplus_cards:generateDebugSources,
>   :vplus_launcher:generateDebugSources,
>   :vplus_settings:generateDebugSources,
>   :vplus_transactions:generateDebugSources,
>   :vplus_payment:generateDebugSources,
>   :vplus_common:generateDebugSources,
>   :vplus_account:generateDebugSources,
>   :vplus_commonres:generateDebugSources,
>   :vplus_bootstrap:generateDebugSources,
>   :vplus_logger:generateDebugSources]
>
> 13:44 Gradle sync finished in 27 s 126 ms
>
> 13:44 Gradle build finished in 4 s 666 ms
>
> 13:45 * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
>
> 13:45 * daemon started successfully
>
> 13:45 Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> 13:46 Gradle build finished in 33 s 640 ms

Answer (score 20):

**Solution 1**

Click drop-down menu with your configuration and choose `Edit Configurations…`

[image: Edit Configurations…]

Select tab General and add `-t` to `Install Flags` field. Click Ok.

[image: Install Flags]

Now start the application again and it should work.

**Solution 2**

> This means that, the shared application has some test packages, so
>   unless those has been removed and source is recompiled, you will not
>   be able to install this apk. But adb command provides a flag “-t”
>   using which you can install the apps with test packages.

```
$ adb install -r -t YourAndroidApp.apk
2566 KB/s (7266004 bytes in 2.764s)
Success
```

**Solution 3**

This error might occur if you moved the project from other computer where it was stored in different directory. To resolve the problem: `Clean the project` and build it again.

**Solution 4**

Go to “`Settings`” -> “`Build, execution, deployment`” and disable “`instant run` to hot swap code…”

**Solution 5**
Add this line to `gradle.properties`:

```
android.injected.testOnly = false
```

Comment: clean build is fine for me try once..

Answer (score 7):

If you would like to manually install an APK or give it to someone for manual installation using the following adb command, then you should only build the APK from the Menu bar -> Build -> Build Bundle/APK.

```
 adb install -r xyz.apk
```

Do not click on the play button as it builds the APK for test purposes only. Clicking on the play button overrides the APK in the default location which can then be installed manually by using the following command only.

```
adb install -r -t xyz.apk
```

Comment: Building debug apk also may lead to this error.

Comment: with -t flag it works :) thanks

Answer (score 4):

**In my case adb commend with -t is working fine**. But I was struggling to share the debug build for testing with anyone who don't have adb setup on their system.

So Just in case if anyone facing the same issue, I am posting the solution

After a long struggle, I am able to figure out

That this was happening because of below code added in build.gradle file.

```
defaultConfig {
    compileSdkPreview = "UpsideDownCake"
}
```

And I had added this code because of **core-ktx version** below issue

```
Dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha03' requires libraries and applications that
depend on it to compile against codename "UpsideDownCake" of the
Android APIs.
     
:app is currently compiled against android-33.
     
Recommended action: Use a different version of dependency 'androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha03',
or set compileSdkPreview to "UpsideDownCake" in your build.gradle
file if you intend to experiment with that preview SDK.
```

So I forced core-ktx version by below code writting above the dependencies block

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core') {
            details.useVersion "1.9.0"
        }
    }
}
```

and removed

```
defaultConfig {
    compileSdkPreview = "UpsideDownCake"
}
```

After that I am not facing any issue in installing debug build and sharing it with others.

PS: I would like to know if anyone else is facing the same issue or different issue, Or would like to share their thoughts on this solution.

Comment: I tried everything... only this worked... thanks!